# Как узнать есть ли скрытые атрибуты у экземпляра класса?

Tags: python, ооп, классы

```
class Person:
    __slots__ = 'name', 'lastname'
    def __init__(self, name, lastname):
        self.name = name
        self.lastname = lastname

class Student(Person):
    pass
```

У экземпляров класса Person доступны только атрибуты представленные в слотах. 
Класс Student может иметь и другие атрибуты помимо унаследованных от класса Person. А также экземплярам класса Student доступен `__dict__`, который содержит в себе ключи атрибутов, но в нем будут отсутствовать атрибуты name и lastname.

Существует какой-нибудь property или магический метод, который дает программисту узнать есть ли у экземпляра иные атрибуты помимо представленных в  `__dict__`?

Comment: `dir(Student)` ?

Comment: Точно. Так и есть. Правда он немного перегружен другими атрибутами и методами унаследованными от класса object, но это ерунда. Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Встроенная функция [`dir([objct])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir). Если ей передать в качестве аргумента объект класса, то она вернет все атрибуты данного класса и все атрибуты всех классов родителей (рекурсивно).

Пример:

```
In [10]: dir(Student)
Out[10]:
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__slots__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 'lastname',
 'name']
```

Method Resolution Order:

```
In [11]: Student.mro()
Out[11]: [__main__.Student, __main__.Person, object]
```